# SSRS Changes User Email in Subscription

Tags: email, reporting-services, subscription

We have a user with a subscription to an SSRS report.  His email is (with last name & domain changed to protect his identity):

dexter.name@company.com

Periodically he won't receive his reports and if we investigate find that his email has been changed to "dexter.".

What could cause this?

Comment: is it data driven subscription?

Comment: No, it's not data driven